# Save data on S3 using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3

I want to collect data entered by the user in a browser and save to Amazon S3.  Is this something I can do with Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I'm going to go down the route of using Amazon web services to store data.  Right now that looks my best bet. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and as I already pointed in the comments of the accepted answer there are legitimate and useful uses to do so without compromising security and credentials.

You can post objects to S3 directly from the browser:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and think I've found a solution. S3 has a [REST interface](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html) to which you can POST data directly, without exposing your AWS Secret Key. So, you can construct an AJAX POST request to your S3 bucket endpoint using Javascript or jQuery. You can specify an access policy in the request as well, which restricts upload access to only certain buckets and certain directories.

Amazon verifies the authenticity of your requests using an HMAC signature which you provide in the request. The signature is constructed using details about the request and your AWS Secret Key, which only you and Amazon know, so fraudulent requests can't be made without someone having a valid signature.

Comment: Thanks Dan, good to know. I ended up serving my javascript widget from S3, then using easyxdm to make a cross domain post to my web server to store the information.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea:

1) Think of how much fun people could have with emptying your bank account when they find your S3 credentials embedded in your Javascript code.

2) The javascript would be loaded from your server and trying to talk to Amazon's servers - that's forbidden as it's cross-domain communication.

Something like this you'd want to handle on the server. You could easily whip up an AJAX interface to send the data `client browser -> your server -> amazon`. That way your S3 credentials are store on your server and not transmitted willy-nilly to everyone using your site.

Comment: Is there anyway of passing the information to javascript running on S3 or an amazon service?  Regarding point 2, could the javascript be served from S3?

Comment: Javascript's a client-side language, generally. It has no native database capabilities, so you couldn't use it (for instance) to talk to MySQL. I'm sure it could be served, but I don't know much at all about S3, so can't say for sure either way.

Comment: Yep I'm specifically asking about S3, no worries perhaps someone else can chip in.  Cheers

Comment: Tigger, you could hack something together to send data from the page to S3 directly via jQuery -- I'm sure you can, given time. The point is: you would have to expose your S3 credentials, which is something you do NOT want to do. You need a gateway(read: `a server`)

Comment: Hi Horia, I'm going to go down the route of using Amazon web services to save data from the client.  Cheers

Comment: +1 On security considerations. But, while it is something that should be avoided by all means (even by people I don't like), it is theoretically possible (not that i have seen any implementations yet) by using websockets (similar to the way flash does it). Since websockets themselves are not supported by stable versions of most browsers out there it is currently impractical (and have I mentioned unsafe), so I would recommend you try [flash based approach](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1092?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) if you really need direct upload to S3.

Comment: Downvoted because it just gives personal opinion without answering the question. An example for a useful client side javascript to access the S3 directly will be a simple js app where each user can use its credentials to upload pictures to S3. It's safe because its his credentials and its safe because he does not give the credentials to anyone else.

Comment: Downvoted because a solution client browser > server > Amazon is not what the question was seeking... in this way you will have useless bandwidth usage on server side (that maybe not in Amazon data center) and more time to complete operation. And, as Dan and Stefan said in the answer below, there is a way to enable HTTP POST to Amazon without expose the password.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at node.js, and try the aws-sdk package by:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

There are blog and doc I found about how to upload files to S3:

[this blog.](http://codeartists.com/post/36892733572/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-your) and
[aws doc.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of issues with attempting to access S3 via client-side code:

- There is no way to secure your credentials.
- Many responses are in XML instead of JSON, and the XML parsing engine in JavaScript is heavy and slow.
- Authenticating the requests would require JavaScript implementations of HMAC-SHA1.
- There are issues with making cross-domain requests from JavaScript without routing through a proxy.

All-in-all, there are no feasible solutions for client-side JavaScript at the moment. If you're interested in server-side JavaScript, there are some S3 classes floating around GitHub for Node.js.

Comment: thanks Skyler - I'm slowly starting to understand a bit more about S3.  At the moment a customer can add a script reference in their page to my js on S3 and that works ok.  But i want them to be able to click a button and have the js send data to me.  I'm now thinking it may be best to setup a web service on my web site and have the js call it.  Can you see any cross-domain issues with this?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is a way to authenticate the request by creating a unique, signed signature for each request, then  including that in a POST request directly to S3. The signature can be generated by your server, so that no HMAC implementation is required on the client side and your AWS credentials remain secure.